# How can I automate AWS Route53 DNS update based on EC2 instance tag names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I want to implement an automatic way of updating Route53 DNS based on EC2 tags of the instances.

Imagine that I can have a tag name named dns_name which is supposed to document the expected dns name of the machine.

If I shutdown the machine, upgrade it and start it again, I do want to get the DNS updated without having to change anything.

I don't want to install a DNS update service on the machine as this would require me to put AWS credentials on all the VMs, and to deploy this to them.

It seems much easier to use AWS EC2 tags to declare the expected names. A cron job could easily check for changes and update the DNS.

Did anyone implement this?

Comment: Do the update on boot of the machine. You don't need to load any credentials on to the instances, just configure them to be launched with an IAM Role that allows R53 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using Elastic IP's. This is the exact purpose of them. For this implementation, go to `EC2` => `Network & Security` => `Elastic IP` => `Allocate New Address` => `Actions` => `Associate Address` => (select the instance tag name you're looking for)

Copy the `EIP` to your clipboard then go to `Route53` => `Create Hosted Zone` => go thought those steps => `Go to Record Sets` => `Create Record Set` => For `Name:` you can have your `www.` or not => `Type: A - IPv4` => `Alias: NO` => `TTL:` Whatever you'd like => `Value:` ***your `EIP` address*** => `Save Record Set`

If you have an Elastic IP associated to your instance, you can reboot, swap, stop, update, change, shape shift, whatever your want! EIP's wont go anywhere.

**Update:**
You can make all this automated via the Route53 API.
These are the steps for doing it because you have to know the process in order to do it with the API calls.

Comment: Elastic IPs are a limited resource and aren't going to work for everyone in all instances.

Comment: That's clearly not an automated way of doing it, and that was my #1 priority.

Comment: There is an API for all of this... Just make the calls of registering and associating and swap the EIP around. Route53 API

Comment: And plus with this method, you don't have to associate every time. The two stay connected all the time

Comment: Just about every AWS resource and their functions have API. That's the whole idea

Comment: Amazon only allows 5 elastic IPs per account.  That's a drastic limitation which makes this suggestion useless when your elastic IPs are already being used.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS update service on the machine wouldn't require AWS credentials. You would preferably use AWS IAM instance profiles instead. I've used this method to run a script on server boot to update Route53 records with the latest IP address.

If you want to schedule a cron on a single server that handles updating the Route53 records for all servers, based on instance tags, then that is certainly possible. It would only be a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do exactly what I think your attempting to do.

What I've found is this script from this link which is a good starting point.

https://medium.com/@dbclin/a-bash-script-to-update-an-existing-aws-security-group-with-my-new-public-ip-address-d0c965d67f28

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extract information about the Instance
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/)
AZ=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/)
MY_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/)

# Extract tags associated with instance
ZONE_TAG=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region ${AZ::-1} --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=${INSTANCE_ID}" --query 'Tags[?Key==`AUTO_DNS_ZONE`].Value' --output text)
NAME_TAG=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region ${AZ::-1} --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=${INSTANCE_ID}" --query 'Tags[?Key==`AUTO_DNS_NAME`].Value' --output text)

# Update Route 53 Record Set based on the Name tag to the current Public IP address of the Instance
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $ZONE_TAG --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"'$NAME_TAG'","Type":"A","TTL":300,"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"'$MY_IP'"}]}}]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This has details of the solution suggested by Mark B.  Elastic IP doesn't work if you don't have any available and Amazon allows you only 5.

I used user14441273's pasted script as a starting point.  The provided link for that is dead (redirects you to an article nothing to do with Route53), and the post gives no clue how to set up the required tags ZONE_TAG or NAME_TAG.

Regardless how you do it, you will need to allow the actions to the instance profile role.

Here's the productonlized working script.  I get the instance name from local file system, which is much faster and more reliable than using a network service.  Change the domain to the domain you want to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
shopt -s xpg_echo
set +u

DNS_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
TTL_S=30  # You want this low or you will have to wait up to this long for changes to propagate

PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

# Extract information about the Instance
INSTNAME=$(ls -ld /var/lib/cloud/instance | sed 's@.*/@@;')
[ -n "$INSTNAME" ] || {
    echo 'Failed to determine Instance name' 1>&2
    false
}
[ -f /tmp/date.txt ] && {
      echo "date present" 1>&2
    false
}
AWS_REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone  | sed 's/.$//')
[ -n "$AWS_REGION" ] || {
    echo 'Failed to determine AWS Region' 1>&2
    false
}
HOSTNAME=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region $AWS_REGION --filters Name=resource-type,Values=instance Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTNAME Name=key,Values=Name --query 'Tags[0].Value' --output text) 
[ -n "$HOSTNAME" ] || {
    echo 'Failed to determine DNS Hostname to update' 1>&2
    false
}
MY_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/)
[ -n "$MY_IP" ] || {
    echo 'Failed to determine my public IP address' 1>&2
    false
}
ZONE_ID=$(aws route53 --region $AWS_REGION list-hosted-zones-by-name --region $AWS_REGION --dns-name $DNS_DOMAIN --query 'HostedZones[0].Id' --output text)
[ -n "$ZONE_ID" ] || {
    echo 'Failed to determine my Route53 Zone ID' 1>&2
    false
}

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $ZONE_ID --region $AWS_REGION --change-batch '{"Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"'${HOSTNAME}.$DNS_DOMAIN'","Type":"A","TTL":'$TTL_S',"ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"'$MY_IP'"}]}}]}'
enter code here
```

Assuming that you're running a late-model Linux variant, here's a working service script.  N.b. I have it configured to run the shell script from /usr/local/sbin which I have NFS mounted:

```
[Unit]
Description=Update Route53 DNS Service with instance's current public IP addr
RequiresMountsFor=/usr/local

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/updateRoute53.bash
RemainAfterExit=no
StandardOutput=truncate:/var/log/updateRoute53.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```